# Innerhtml disables video src

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

Why does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XDfaceme/ngHKE/) not work, while [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XDfaceme/ngHKE/1) works. The only diffrence is that in the second case, I added the video elements in the html file instead of adding them through the innerHTML method.

```
document.querySelector('#top').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#top').innerHTML + "<video id='vid" + id + "'></video>";
```

Should create this

```
<video id="vid0"></video>
<video id="vid1"></video>
```

But when looking at the debugging window in chrome, i see that in that when I create the video tags in javascript, the src element of the first video doesnt appear. Which not happens when i add them manually to the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems (I think!):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= vids; i++)
```

`vids` ends up being 2, so this is trying to set src for video[0], video[1] and video[2], whereas you've only created two videos.

Also in this:

```
height = video[id].videoHeight / (video[id].videoWidth / width);
```

`video[id].videoHeight` is not defined, so the height ends up being NaN.